# Shell script replace start and end of string by matching pattern

Tags: string, shell, replace

Can I use a shell script command to replace all occurrence of a pattern from part of the string and keep the remaining part e.g. `[XXXX]important[YYYYY]` so whereever there is patterns `[XXXX]anything[YYYYY]` becomes 'anything'

```
Input         | Output
[XXXX]1[YYYY] | 1
[XXXX]2[YYYY] | 2
```

Comment: The short answer is : yes probably. Now, please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see what you tried and where it failed. Did you try something like `sed -r 's/^[XXXX](.*)[YYYY]$/\1/' `?

Comment: Hello All, Thanks for replying. I was able to do it using sed, the actual problem was transforming mongodb export data into a format which can be directly uploaded on google bigquery. This sed worked in transforming - sed -i -e 's/{"$numberLong":"\([0-9]*\)"}/\1/g;s/:\([0-9]*\)\.0,/:\1,/g' <FILE PATH>